# Why my int[][] is filled with 1 instead of 0?

Tags: java

I'm doing my project with a mouse in the room looking for cheese. 
In short, I have a board filled with 0 (empty), 1 (random cheese) and 2 (random mouse). First console display is correct, but the second one changes 0 to 1. Any ideas what happened?

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int cheese = 53 + random.nextInt(477);
    int mouseX = random.nextInt(23);
    int mouseY = random.nextInt(23);

    int[][] room = new int[23][23];

    for(int i = 0; i< room.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < room.length; j++) {
            room[i][j] = 0; //empty room

            for (int l = 0; l <= cheese; l++) {
                int m = random.nextInt(23);
                int n = random.nextInt(23);
                room[m][n] = 1; //cheese
            }
            room[mouseY][mouseX] = 2;// mouse

            System.out.print(room[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Cheese amount: " + cheese);
    System.out.println("Mouse position: " + mouseY + ", " + mouseX);

    for(int i = 0; i < room.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < room.length; j++){
            System.out.print(room[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Comment: You're adding the max amount of cheese chosen in a loop but this runs for every i / j combination since it's inside the two other for loops

Comment: The second part of the code that adds random cheese and the mouse in *within* the  loop that initialises the array which surely can't be want you want?  In any case the array will already be initialised to zeroes so you don't need that loop anyway.

Comment: another problem with this code is that mouse position can override cheese position

Comment: What do you mean by "is correct"? What do you expect to see, and what do you actually see? It may help to do this with a smaller grid so you can show your results more concisely. (answer these questions by editing the question)

Comment: In the first printing logic, you are not done writing all the i/j combinations you are going to write. In the second print logic, all combinations (randomly most) are made 1. Hence at the second time most of the 0 are converted to 1.

Comment: As @Patrick said your loops are nested.
It may be worth separating what you are doing into stages and trying each one in turn to see what is happening e.g. 
First fill room with 0's, 
Print the result to see this has happened, 
Next randomly add the cheese, 
Print the result, 
Finally add the mouse and print out the final result.

I'd also suggest using slightly better names than i,j,l,m and n for variable names.

Comment: I suggest you generate one-dimensional array with certain amount of cheese and mice, shuffle it, then map to two-dimensional array. It will be clearer and simplier.

Comment: @trollingchar you are speculating about the requirement. Let's let OP explain to us what they need.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the description, what logically the code does. We will use 2 terms, first is `tile` (single spot where You put mouse, cheese, or nothing) and `room` (2D array that consists of `tiles`).

1. create some variables (count of cheese that you plant) + create `room`
2. Go throught full size of `room` in both directions (X,Y) for every `tile`:

   - set `tile` to 0 - empty it ( `room[i][j] = 0;` )
   - go throught all available cheese count (from 0 to `cheese` count):

     - select random X,Y `tile` and set it to be a cheese (`room[m][n] = 1;`)
     - repeat until all available cheese set
   - set mouse to random tile
   - **repeat step 2. -> the cycle, for next `tile` in `room`**
3. do the rest (like print array + results)

---

If you go from top to bottom, you will cycle around the point 2. again and again. That means:

- you set **1st** `tile` to 0, set random amount `tiles` to be cheese, set random mouse
- you set **2nd** `tile` to 0, set random amount `tiles` to be cheese, set random mouse
- you set **3rd** `tile` to 0, set random amount `tiles` to be cheese, set random mouse
- ...
- you set **last** `tile` to 0, set random amount `tiles` to be cheese, set random mouse

---

Issue there is simply that You should put the code that fills random cheese under the `for` cycle of emptying the field:

```
for(int i = 0; i< room.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < room.length; j++) {
        room[i][j] = 0; //empty room
    }
}

for (int l = 0; l <= cheese; l++) {
    int m = random.nextInt(23);
    int n = random.nextInt(23);
    room[m][n] = 1; //cheese
}

room[mouseY][mouseX] = 2;// mouse 
//note that the row above can overwrite already existing cheese, algorithm may need optimization because of that
```

Comment: This should work fine and if OP is worried about overwriting they would just have to check that `m,n` is not the same as `mouseY, mouseX` or the other way around.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine now. I did not know, that the loop in the loop will run again. I do not mind overriding a cheese by a mouse. It does not matter.

Comment: @Hanna This is commonly refered as `Nested looping`, whatever is in the brackets `{ }`, will run together again.

Comment: @Hanna if the answer has helped you, please consider setting it as a final answer (mark on the left). Thanks! =)